# Selenium ".check" Function Not Recognized

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, watir, firewatir

I have created an object using Selenium:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

I am attempting to make use of the "check" function for a radio button like so:

```
driver.find_element(:name => "SomeName").check
```

However, this comes up with an error:

```
in `<main>': undefined method `check' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x35c75e8>
```

Is there another way to select radio buttons in Selenium with Ruby that I am just not seeing anywhere?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Using the find_element.click function does not work either. For instance:

```
    <td valign="middle"><input type="radio" NAME="TESTNAME" VALUE="TESTVALUE1"></td>
    <td valign="middle"><input type="radio" NAME="TESTNAME" VALUE="TESTVALUE2"></td>
    <td valign="middle"><input type="radio" NAME="TESTNAME" VALUE="TESTVALUE3" ></td>
```

Performing:

```
driver.find_element(:name => "TESTNAME", :value => "TESTVALUE3" ).click
```

Does not do anything. Any feedback on why this is case would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Element#click. The API docs for the Selenium::WebDriver::Element class can be found [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/2.0.0/Selenium/WebDriver/Element).

Comment: I tried this before as well. While it does not throw an error, it still does not perform the desired outcome. I've edited my post with this specific case.